# "Send Survey" Action not showing on lightning record page

Tags: action, lightning-quickaction, lightning-record-page

[image]

Submit for Approval works, Send Survey action has no filters, this is dynamic layout, but still it cannot be displayed. Anyone know why? This is the Case object.